# Varchar type to numeric. Convert Years to months in SQL (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, numeric, varchar

I am trying to convert both of the columns TOJ and TAR to a numeric number without MOS and YRS characters.
For example, 18 YRS 0 MOS needs to be (18 * 12 + 0 = 216 months).

Table name is `ld2`.

| TOJ | TAR |
| --- | --- |
| 8YRS 0MOS | 14YRS 0MOS |
| 12YRS 0MOS | 6YRS 0MOS |
| 5YRS 0MOS | 0YRS 4MOS |
| 0YRS 6MOS | 26YRS 0MOS |
| 1YRS 0MOS | 1YRS 0MOS |

[More sample data (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTh6V.jpg)

I tried this:

```
select substring(TOJ,PATINDEX('%[0,9]%',TOJ), LEN(TOJ))
```

to get onlt the numbers in TOJ But did not work.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data *as text tables*.  Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Instead post code as plain text, formatted as “code”. If there’s an error, include it in your question.

Comment: Please REMOVE the image.... (If you check the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDUyf.jp), you will know why to remove it....)

Comment: The function [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), returns a value you do not expect. Did you check the output of `SELECT PATINDEX('%[0,9]%',TOJ), substring(TOJ,PATINDEX('%[0,9]%',TOJ), LEN(TOJ))`  ?  Maybe check the [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. It seems better fit for this purpose.

Comment: `[0,9]` is not the right way to represent a digit match. And besides you probably want to split on the space character rather then searching for numerics.

Comment: Grabbing everything from first digit to end would just give you the whole string back.

Answer (score 1):

```
cast(trim(replace(left(s, 2), 'Y', '')) as int) * 12 +
cast(trim(replace(left(right(s, 5), 2), 'M', '')) as int)
```

Assumes the format is consistent and that year (and month) can only have two digits.

Comment: How do we convert the VARCHAR type (result) to a decimal?

Comment: It's already an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOJ, CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TOJ,'YRS','.'),'MOS',''),' ',''));
```

- First replace, replaces 'YRS' by '.'
- Second replace, replaces 'MOS' by ''
- Third replace, removes spaces (replaces ' ' by '')

If you started with '27YRS 7MOS', the replacing should end up with '27.7'.

If you convert '27.7' to a decimal, you should get the desired value.

EDIT:
Reason for edit: months are not base 10.....

Comment: In the original question was '.. convert to DECIMAL', od did I really mis-read that ?

```
select c, (c-c%1)*12 + CASE WHEN PARSENAME(c,1)%10=0 THEN PARSENAME(c,1)/10 ELSE PARSENAME(c,1) END
from (
select 
   TOJ t, 
   CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TOJ,'YRS','.'),'MOS',''),' ','')) c) s;
```

With the test data (that is provided now): [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3944005ba5fbf59120bd33d7e82b5279)

Comment: But months aren't base 10.